# How to add multiple items to RecyclerView on Button Click?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add details of movies to Recyclerview on Button Click. I have 2 Activities. I can add the details of movies in the first activity and I can view the list of movies in the Second Activity. The first activity contains a submit button to add movies.

[image]

But the issue I'm facing is that I can add movies to the first row only. If i try to add another movie it replaces the first row. I want to create a list of movies on button click. How do I do this? The below code is the Main Activity (First Activity).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setActionBarColour();
        clickEvents();

    }

    private void clickEvents()
    {
        final EditText editTextMovieName = findViewById(R.id.movieName);
        final EditText editTextGenre = findViewById(R.id.genre);
        final EditText editTextReleaseYear = findViewById(R.id.year);

        Button submit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        Button movieList = findViewById(R.id.btnMovieList);

        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = editTextMovieName.getText().toString();
                String genre = editTextGenre.getText().toString();
                String year = editTextReleaseYear.getText().toString();

                bundle.putString("MOVIE_NAME", name);
                bundle.putString("GENRE", genre);
                bundle.putString("YEAR", year);
            }
        });

        movieList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovieListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setActionBarColour()
    {
        ActionBar actionBar;
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3498DB"));
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
    }
}
```

This below code is only a function in the Second Activity to get the data

```
private void prepareMovieData()
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        String movieName = bundle.getString("MOVIE_NAME");
        String genre = bundle.getString("GENRE");
        String year = bundle.getString("YEAR");

        Movie movie = new Movie(movieName,genre,year);
        movieList.add(movie);

    }
```

If I edit the above code to

```
        Movie movie = new Movie(movieName,genre,year);
        movieList.add(movie);        

        Movie movie2 = new Movie(movieName,genre,year);
        movieList.add(movie2);
```

I can add only 2 movies. If i want to put 3 movies then I would have to put a third statement like this

```
        Movie movie3 = new Movie(movieName,genre,year);
        movieList.add(movie3);
```

The more movies I want the more lines of code I have to write. So how do I put a large number of movies on click?

Comment: on button click just add the object in your `movieList` and notify your adapter

Comment: Thats because your movieslist is always initialized with 0 item.. you should store the list whenever item is inserted. you can use shared pref or database. other way is your movies detail Activity  should return the data to List activity. onActivityResult, add the item to list and pass the list to adapter.For that you have to call the List Activity first and call detail activity from List Activity. so that it could return list.

Comment: I use broadcast to send the movies to MovieListActivity. Then from the MovieListActivity I pass the data to the Movie Class. The Adapter gets the details from the Movie Class and displays the details in the Movie List Activity. Do you want to see the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question detailing we can conclude that

1) On Submit move to next Activity with movie details and add in adapter.

2) Press back

3) Repeat step 1 with new details.

**So here revisiting next screen will not have previous data. For that you have to save data in local storage and display.**

Comment: I didn't experience what you said in Bold. I still have the previous data. My problem is that I need to insert multiple movies. I'm only able to add one.

Comment: I still have the previous data-> How you found this? Are you storing somewhere?

Comment: I don't store it any where. But if I exit my App and start the app again, then the data is lost. But if I just change activities without quitting the app the data exist. I test this in the emulator. By the way I edited my question a bit towards the end.

Comment: My friend, this is very basics of Android, and have very long answer.The conclusion is you are sending single data, which will display overriding the previous one

Comment: I want to display the previous data too as in a list. For example I should be able to add "Harry Potter", "The Avengers" and many other movies I can into the list. But the problem now I'm facing is that if I add my second movie after inserting the first it overides the first movie so that this new movies is visible and not the first movie that i added. I want to see both the movies which i added not just the most recently added one

Answer (score 0):

As i review your code when you call the second activity its clear your model data  and make its easy use parcable data into model class which help you to pass the model class from one activity to another use onActivityresult for this and add this you model into list to add multiple data through intent. or you can save your data into local sql-lite and fetch data into next activity